# Feature Selection(Boruta)

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-science, feature-selection

I'm doing credit risk modelling and the data have large number of features.I am using boruta package for feature selection. The package is too computationally expensive, I cannot run it on the complete training dataset. What i'm trying to do is take a subset of the training data(let's say about 20-30%) and run the boruta package on that subsetted data and get the important features. But when i use random forest to train the data I have too use the full dataset. My question is, Is it right to select features only on a part of train data but then build the model on whole of training data?

Comment: Its not wrong considering sample 'is SRS without replacement' and have enough entries to build model with good accuracy'. Try this exercise 2-3 times just to be sure. What do you mean by computationally expensive? How much are data size and computing resources?

Comment: The size is about 150 mb. I'm running it on R studio. PC specs : 8gb ram, 6th gen i5

Comment: From byte size perspective, 150MB is not big data size. You have enough resources to process. I was asking about numbers of observations. How much time it takes to process this data?

Comment: I have about 0.5 million observations each of 19 variables. I ran the boruta feature selection algorithm on 50% of this data and it took about 75 minutes, that too on third try. My laptop hanged midway the first two times.Also the rfe feature selection didnot produce any result for 30 minutes.

Comment: Try with 30% sample size. One more thing you can check is faster implementations of boruta algo in other packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is logical in nature, I will give my two cents.

1. A single random sample of 20% of the population is good enough i believe
2. A step further would be taking 3-4 such random sets and the intersection of the significant variables from all of them is an improvement to the above
3. Using feature selection from multiple methods (xgboost, some caret feature selection methods) -> use a different random sample for each of them, and then take the common significant features

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the above suggestions.

Comment: Just saw your post on the size of the dataset. 500k observations and just 19 variables isnt much actually. Are you sure you need to do feature selection? In case you have to, use xgboost package to create a model. It does inbuilt feature selection. Then use the importance function from the package to get the significance of the variables in the model. Takes about 2-3 minutes for me for the whole process with 500k observations and more than 300 features on a system with your same specs.